# How do I count amount of X mentioned?

Tags: python, xlrd

I want to count how many times someone has been mentioned if they've been mentioned.

I've tried to count the user with visually the most amount of mentions (this is a twitter excel file) being GhostKumi with the code below

```py
s = sheet.col(19)

c = s.count('GhostKumi')

print(c)
```

Although it returns with

```
0
```

Which isn't quite right considering;

```
mentions
GhostKumi
GhostKumi
MasryLando
CamUnivMuseums
GhostKumi
CamUnivMuseums
CamUnivMuseums
GhostKumi
GhostKumi
GhostKumi
CamUnivMuseums
```

This is the mentions column.

```py
for c1, c2, c3 in zip(sheet.col(23), sheet.col(11), sheet.col(19)):
    print("username:",c1.value) 
    print("has:",c2.value, "retweets")
    print("and mentioned:",c3.value)
    print("***********************")


s = sheet.col(19)

c = s.count('GhostKumi')

print(c)
```

This is the whole code (which shows mentions usernames and the amount of retweets the user has on a pulled thread from twitter)

The outcome as stated above was 0 which isn't right, and I'd also like to find a way to find matches and count then print those

Assuming the data is this;

```
mentions
GhostKumi
GhostKumi
MasryLando
CamUnivMuseums
GhostKumi
CamUnivMuseums
CamUnivMuseums
GhostKumi
GhostKumi
GhostKumi
CamUnivMuseums
```

For example:

```
GhostKumi: 6 mention(s)
CamUnivMuseums: 4 mention(s)
MasryLando: 1 mention(s)
```

And to state which of those users have the most:

```
GhostKumi: 6 mention(s) (Most)
MasryLando: 1 mention(s) (Least)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Sheet.col` [returns a `list` of `Cell` objects](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/bbccdcb96e40b590d71ed14682237bea1e8f1dc5/xlrd/sheet.py#L547).

Python's `list.count` method will do a simple comparison of the passed in value to try to count the number of instances. However, a `Cell` and a `str` won't ever be equal. In fact, `xldr`'s `Cell` class [doesn't even define an `__eq__` method](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/bbccdcb96e40b590d71ed14682237bea1e8f1dc5/xlrd/sheet.py#L2255).

Instead of calling `count` on the `list`, you might instead filter the list of `Cell`s and take the length of that list:

```py
c = len([cell for cell in sheet.col(x) if cell.value == 'GhostKumi'])
```

Comment: I tried to implement this however I got the error:
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: It's updated now. It was due to not turning the result of the comprehension back into a list before passing it to `len`.